# Calculating the mean of a numeric vector

Tags: r, csv, mean

I am reading a .csv file and trying to do the following:

1. remove the commas from column V5, which is the gdp of 190 countries
2. find the average of all those numbers

This is my code thus far:

```
gdp <- read.csv("GDP.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip=5, nrows=190)
x <- gsub(",", "", gdp$V5)
y <- as.numeric(x)
```

when I use

```
mean(y)
```

NA is returned rather than a mean. What am I doing wrong?

Source file: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FGDP.csv

Comment: try `mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: This worked, but did not yield a matching mean (I'm trying to answer a multiple choice question and the mean from the choices does not match the output I get when running the above code.

Comment: When I run that exact script, I get the following: 'code' Error: unexpected ']' in "x[is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x))]"

Comment: I didn't get `NA`. The mean I get is `377652.4` what is the mean in your question? Also, if you will open your file in Excel and check the mean of first 190 rows, it will also result in `377652`. So you question has an error.

Comment: @MrFlick You need one more closing `)` in that: `x[is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x)))]`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Silly typo. But it won't let me edit anymore. I'll delete mine and leave yours up for posterity.

Comment: Thank all. Something was wrong with the first .csv file I downloaded (I went into the file using excel and must have mucked it up!). I re-downloaded the file and using the script above, it worked and I get a mean of 377652 as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need remove spaces too (as you can see, the values are something like `"    X"`). This works:

```
gdp <- read.csv("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FGDP.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip=5, nrows=190)
x <- gsub(",| ", "", gdp$V5)
y <- as.numeric(x)
mean(y)
```

Comment: I tried this, but mean(y) still returns NA.

Comment: The question I am trying to answer is the following:Remove the commas from the GDP numbers in millions of dollars and average them. What is the average? I've run this code now, that seems to work: 'gdp <- read.csv("GDP.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip=5, nrows=190)
x <- gsub(",| ", "", gdp$V5)
y <- as.numeric(x)
mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)' But the output does not match a multiple choice question I am trying to answer. So somehow, I'm not getting the correct mean ???

Comment: The reason I was getting the wrong mean is because my .csv file had been manipulated (by me) and apparently that corrupted the calculation of correct mean. When I downloaded the file anew, I ran the script above, and was able to obtain the correct mean.

Thank you, Stack Overflow community!